# how to use datasets from data.gov

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dataset

I am doing Ruby programming and want to call some datasets from the Data.gov website to my app. But I am not knowing how can I use the datasets from Data.gov. I know this should be posted on their site but I found no real active blog or something. I would be glad if anyone can help me with this or have used the datasets from data.gov.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

They offer the data as a csv file which is a file containint one dataset per line and the columns are seperated by a commata. There are some functions in ruby to parse CSV files.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

But if you want an interface to automaticly grab all the data you will need to write your own. I use mechanize and nokogiri to automize website calls. The problem you would have then is that every .csv has his own table structure so you cant import them to a pre defined model.

Comment: Damn you got some problems reading? I wrote that he can use mechanize and nokogiri to automaticly fetch all the csv's. I didnt say a word parsing CSV with mechanize or nokogiri. The thing about the table structure is logical. You cant write the data of several CSVs to one table in your database because they all have different information and count of columns!

Comment: Why would he use mechanize over the much simpler open-uri? What does nokogiri (an html parser) have to do with csv? Where did he mention tables or databases? This was a poor answer.

Comment: He said he wants to handle with data and that contains that he might wants to automaticly import the data from data.gov, he said "some datasets" thats plural. I hate quoting myself but I wrote :"I use mechanize and nokogiri to automize website calls." I explicitly talked about website calls not about parsing CSV what you assume to me! And if he doesnt want to automize it, well I answered that main qestion first. Learn english dude!

Answer (score 0):

See if this gem meets your needs. If nothing else you can probably look at the source code and learn.

https://github.com/sunlightlabs/datacatalog-imp-data-gov